# How to use the ElasticSearch Java API to build an Aggregation from JSON string

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to build SearchSourceBuilder using aggregation params as a JSON string. I can build SearchSourceBuilder with queryJson but cannot find a way to add aggregation as a JSON string. I am using 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:jar:7.7.0'

```
"query": {
"range": {
"currentListPrice": {
"gte": 200,
"lte": 240
}
}
}

"aggs": {
"prices_range_200_240_sum": {
"sum": {
"field": "currentListPrice"
}
},
"prices_range_200_240_avg": {
"sum": {
"field": "currentListPrice"
}
}
}
```

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder(String queryJson) {
    var queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(queryJson);
    var builder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    builder.query(queryBuilder);

    return builder;
}
```

I tried building by passing string and byte[] for aggregation but looks like it's not supported

Comment: Wrapper query doesnt works with aggregation.

Comment: do we have a way like builder.aggregation(aggsJson)